# How to print multiple row values in postgres when query executed using EXECUTE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3, dynamicquery

I have below program , My 2nd select query returns multiple records,
How should I print all the values.. Currently its printing only 1st value. 
Can you please suggest?

Ex. Actual Output:

123

890

4599

Current Output:
123

```
DO $$
<<script>>
DECLARE
  student_rec RECORD;
  sqlquery text;
  v_nk RECORD;

BEGIN
FOR student_rec IN 
select nk from course_table;
-- open loop for cursor above
LOOP
sqlquery := 'SELECT col FROM section where rec_nk = ' || '''' ||student_rec.nk ||'''' ;
EXECUTE sqlquery into v_nk; 
raise notice 'Value: %', v_nk;  
END LOOP; 

EXCEPTION when others then    
    raise notice 'Script execution failed.'
                 'Transaction was rolled back.';
    raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;

END script $$;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you have declared `v_nk` as `RECORD`, `SELECT INTO` indeed selects a value into a scalar value, when used in the context of `PL/pgSQL`. See [`SELECT INTO` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) for more details.

If you want to print all records with `RAISE NOTICE` you can loop like this:

```sql
sqlquery := 'SELECT col FROM section WHERE rec_nk = ' || '''' || student_rec.nk || '''' ;

FOR v_nk IN EXECUTE sqlquery
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', v_nk;
    END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already are looping through query result:

```
[ <<label>> ]
FOR target IN query LOOP
    statements
END LOOP [ label ];
```

There is also `FOR-IN-EXECUTE`:

```
[ <<label>> ]
FOR target IN EXECUTE text_expression [ USING expression [, ... ] ] LOOP
    statements
END LOOP [ label ];
```

See [documentation on Looping Through Query Results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).

In your case it would be:

```sql
FOR v_nk IN EXECUTE sqlquery LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', v_nk;
END LOOP;
```